# Why does Virtual Workstation hang when I try to edit virtual machine settings?

Tags: windows-7, vmware-workstation

I am running Windows 7 64-bit. When I try to edit virtual machine settings the program locks up and shuts down. Does anyone else have this problem? And if so does anyone have a fix for this issue? Thanks in advance.

I am running VMWare 7.0 the virtual machine is XP Pro and the host machine is Windows 7.0 64-bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These problems should not happen.

I would suggest uninstalling and reinstalling VMware, turning off UAC for the duration of the installation.